# Efficiently remove rows containing repeating elements between different rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, duplicates, rows

Given a 2D array, I may have a row at index ***i*** that may have one or multiple numbers found in another row at index ***j***. I need to remove those rows ***i*** and ***j*** from the array. 
Also within any row, numbers are always unique to that row. I have solution already without loop, Numpy based. 
Here is the only solution I came up with:

```
def filter_array(arr):
    # Reshape to 1D without hard copy
    arr_1d = arr.ravel()
    # Make a count of only the existing numbers (faster than histogram)
    u_elem, c = np.unique(arr_1d, return_counts=True)
    # Get which elements are duplicates.
    duplicates = u_elem[c > 1]
    # Get the rows where these duplicates belong
    dup_idx = np.concatenate([np.where(arr_1d == d)[0] for d in duplicates])
    dup_rows = np.unique(dup_idx //9)
    # Remove the rows from the array
    b = np.delete(arr, dup_rows, axis=0)
    return b
```

Here is an (over-simplified) example of an input array:

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 3, 23, 40, 33],
    [2, 8, 5, 35, 7],
    [9, 32, 4, 6, 3],
    [72, 85, 32, 48, 53],
    [3, 98, 101, 589, 208],
    [343, 3223, 4043, 65, 78]
])
```

The filtered array gives, which is the expected result although I haven't exhaustively check if this works in all of my possible cases:

```
[[   2    8    5   35    7]
 [ 343 3223 4043   65   78]]
```

My typical array sizes are about 10^5 to 10^6 rows with a fixed number of 9 columns. %timeit give about 270 ms to filter each of such array. I have a hundred million of them. I am trying to speed this up on single cpu before considering other means (e.g. GPUs)

These data may already be living in a Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could achieve a substantial speedup here by using [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) after finding the unique values and their counts, and using the result to index the array:

```
u, c = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
a[np.isin(a, u[c == 1]).all(1)]

array([[   2,    8,    5,   35,    7],
       [ 343, 3223, 4043,   65,   78]])
```

---

Timings:

```
def filter_array(arr):
    arr_1d = arr.ravel()
    u_elem, c = np.unique(arr_1d, return_counts=True)
    duplicates = u_elem[c > 1]
    dup_idx = np.concatenate([np.where(arr_1d == d)[0] for d in duplicates])
    dup_rows = np.unique(dup_idx //9)
    b = np.delete(arr, dup_rows, axis=0)
    return b

def yatu(arr):
    u, c = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
    return arr[np.isin(arr, u[c == 1]).all(1)]

a_large = np.random.randint(0, 50_000, (10_000, 5))

%timeit filter_array(a_large)
# 433 ms ± 25.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit yatu(a_large)
# 7.81 ms ± 443 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Same speed up here on my actual data!